# Validate Cluster - api/v1/nodes: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kops

On my ubuntu 18.04 aws server I try to create cluster via kops.

```
kops create cluster \
  --name=asdf.com \
  --state=s3://asdf \
  --zones=eu-west-1a \
  --node-count=1 \
  --node-size=t2.micro \
  --master-size=t2.micro \
  --master-count=1 \
  --dns-zone=asdf.com \
  --ssh-public-key=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

```
kops update cluster --name asdf.com
```

Succesfully Updated my cluster.
But when i try to validate and try to

```
kubectl get nodes
```

I got the error : Server gave http response to https server

```
kops validate cluster --name asdf.com
```

Validation failed: unexpected error during validation: error listing nodes: Get https://api.asdf.com/api/v1/nodes: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgQhT.png)

I could’nt solve this.

I tried

```
kubectl config set-cluster asdf.com --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true
```

but it didnt work.

Please can you help?

Answer (score 0):

t2.micro instances may be too small for a control plane nodes. They will certainly be very slow in booting properly. You can try omitting that flag (i.e use the default size) and see if that boots up properly.

Tip: use `kops validate cluster --wait=30m` as it may provide more clues to what is wrong.

Except for the instance size, the command above looks good. But if you want to dif deeper, you can have a look at https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/operations/troubleshoot/